# Serving media content with Django and Nginx

Tags: python, django, docker, nginx, django-rest-framework

I am creating `DRF` application, that is hosted on a remote server. I have `PostgreSQL` and `Django Rest Framework` running inside `Docker` containers, and `Nginx` directly on the host.

Now, it works successfully when I make request to *https://example.com/path/to/file* - I get image served by `Nginx` correctly. But my problem is that when `Django` returns me a `JSON` object with data, the `image_url` field (Django's `ImageField` - path to file) is equal to *http://localhost:6500/path/to/file* This 6500 port and localhost are generated by `Docker`. Instead, I supposed it to return this: *https://example.com/path/to/file*.

Here is my `Nginx` file:

```
server {
    server_name api.example.com www.api.example.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/api.example.com-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/api.example.com-error.log;

    location /media/ {
        alias /opt/site_backend_docker/Site_Backend/apps/media/;
    }


    location / {
        client_max_body_size 0;
        gzip off;
        ## https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
        ## Some requests take more than 30 seconds.
        proxy_read_timeout      300;
        proxy_connect_timeout   300;
        proxy_redirect          off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
       listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = api.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name api.example.com www.api.example.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

And my `Django` settings for media content:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = str(APPS_DIR / "media")
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
```

Sorry if my question is silly, it is my first experience with Deploying. I would be very grateful for any help.

P.S. I know that `Amazon S3` and other solutions for serving media in production are incomparably better, but I use the currect one (Django itself) only for now.